# Checking to see what item is selected in an HTML select list via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the actual value (or text) of the item selected in an HTML select box?  Here are the main methods I've tried...

```
document.getElementById('PlaceNames').value
```

```
$("#PlaceNames option:selected").val()
```

```
$("#PlaceNames option:selected").text()
```

And I've tried various variations on these.  All I ultimately want to do is get that data and send it to a web service via AJAX, I just need the string representation of what the user selected.  This seems like it should be really easy and I've even found a question similar to this here, but I'm still having issues getting it worked out.  Google doesn't seem to be helping either.  I feel like it must be due to some fundamental misunderstanding of Javascript and jQuery.

EDIT:  I should mention that I'm using IE7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('#placeNames').val()` returns the [value](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) of the selected option in the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot.  I was doing it this way initially and was getting null returned.  Turns out I was using the Id for an empty list box on the page just below the one I should have been using.  It's been a long day.

Answer (score 1):

Non-jQuery variant:

```
var select = document.getElementById('PlaceNames');
var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
```

Older jQuery variant:

```
var select = $('#PlaceNames:first')[0];
var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
```

Current jQuery variant:

```
var value = $('#PlaceNames:first').val();
```

I'm probably just being overly safe using :first.

Answer (score 0):

var plid = $('#PlaceNames').val();

val placename = $('#PlaceNames option[value=\''+plid.toString()+'\']').html();